# Loading custom language file for plugin

Tags: localization, language

I'm trying to load a custom language file for a plugins to avoid any changes for this file when updating the plugin. I tried several snippets in the functions.php of the theme, but none of them worked.

```
add_filter('load_textdomain_mofile', 'custom_load_textdomain_mofile', 10, 2);
function custom_load_textdomain_mofile( $mofile, $domain){
    if ($domain == 'my-textdomain')
        $mofile = 'path to mo. file';
    return $mofile;
}
```

I tried it with relative and absolute paths and with WP_LANG_DIR. Nothing worked.

Same here:

```
add_action('load_textdomain', 'load_custom_language_files_for_my_plugin', 10, 2);

function load_custom_language_files_for_my_plugin($domain, $mofile)
{
    if ('all-in-one-event-calendar' === $domain && plugin_dir_path($mofile) === WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/all-in-one-event-calendar/languages/')
    {
        load_textdomain('all-in-one-event-calendar', WP_LANG_DIR.'/'.$domain.'-'.get_locale().'.mo');
    }
}
```

Both snipptes seem to be pretty ok. However, the MO file is not loaded.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you will use the translation only in back end, then load the translation file on the hook `admin_init`. If not, also on front end, then use the hook `init`.

A example:

```
class Fb_Example_Class {

    /**
     * Constructor, init the functions inside WP
     *
     * @return  \Fb_Example_Class 
     */
    private function __construct() {

        // load translation files
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'localize_plugin' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Localize_plugin function.
     *
     * @uses    load_plugin_textdomain, plugin_basename
     * @access  public
     * @return  void
     */
    public function localize_plugin() {

        load_plugin_textdomain( 'textdomain', FALSE, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
    }

}
```

You find also helpful content and examples on [the codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain).